# .Net Installation: Overwriting the old version with the new one

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project

I have created an installation project for `Outlook Plugin` application using `Add In Express.`
I wish to create an installation package that would simply overwrite the previous version without asking the user to manually uninstall the previous version.

Well this is becoming a real problem for me. Certainly the internet has some information on this but even with all that info and experimentation I am not able to get out of this.
I have set the property values of the set up project thus:

```
1) DetectNewerInstalledVersion : True
2) InstallAllUsers : True
3) RemovePreviousVersions : True
4) UpgradeCode : Same as in the previous version
5) ProductCode : has been changed by VS itself as I incremented the Version 
   property of the set up project (I clicked yes).
```

I have also incremented the Assembly version of the Outlook Plugin project in the AssemblyInfo.cs class.

**Result**:

---

The `.msi` file on double clicking, installs the new version and does not uninstalls the older version. :(
I am using .`Net 4.0` with `Windows 7`.
Any help is appreciated.

regards,

Comment: What technology are you using? The only one making sense these days is WIX - not the not so smart (diplocamtic words) "stuff" that is in visual studio to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Has TomTom has stated, we need to know what technology you are using. I am going to assume that you are using the Installer package with Visual Studio. To have the installer automatically uninstall your application you need to set **RemovePreviousVersion** to **True** and make sure that you increase the version number of your application by at least the Build number.

[image]

Comment: I have already stated that I have set these property values. I am using .Net 4.0 Set up project!

Comment: Increasing revision number can work as well. I guess the whole point is just to increase original assembly version.